# The type arguments for method The type arguments for method `System.MemoryExtensions.Reverse<T>(this System.Span<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usag

Tags: c#, .net

Why does my code come up with this error? I'm trying to solve the second question on Coderbyte, it's about reversing a string.

Error:

```
Main.cs(8,39): error CS0411: The type arguments for method `System.MemoryExtensions.Reverse<T>(this System.Span<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
```

Code:

```
using System;

class MainClass {

  public static string FirstReverse(string str) {

    
    string backwards = new string(str.Reverse().ToArray());
    return backwards;
  }

  static void Main() {  
    Console.WriteLine(FirstReverse(Console.ReadLine()));
  } 

}
```

Comment: A `string` is not a `Span<char>`.

Answer (score 3):

`String` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-5.0) does not have a method `Reverse`, so the only thing to resolve `Reverse` to is a static extension method available with the `using` directives in your program. From `System` the best the compiler could do is `System.MemoryExtensions.Reverse<T>(this System.Span<T>)` but it couldn't use this because `String` is not a `Span<T>` for any `T`.

You  were probably looking for `Enumerable.Reverse<T>` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=net-5.0) because String is an `IEnumerable<char>`. To use this you will need to include it with `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I like that have explained things, maybe you could add an example of what the op should do with the code given